# How to design a special array list in Python?

Tags: python, text, nlp

I am working on text in NLP. I want to count the co-occurrence of words with windows size 4. it means that for a selected node we consider its left and right locations (-2 -1 +1 +2). For example, we have a list that contains keywords:  `K=[go,to,with]` and we want to check the keywords in left and right of words in a sentence and count number of co-occurrences of them.
for example, suppose we have this sentence: `S=[I go to university to learn every day.].` the window with size 4 for word `university` will be like this: `go to university to learn`. as instance the vector for word `university` is as follows: `university=[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]`. for example if we consider location -2 , we see that only there is word `go`, so we put 1 for it. then in location -1 of word `university` we have word `to`, so `go` and `with` will be zero and only `to` will be equal to 1. as another instance, when we are in +2, none of the words in list`k` is appeared there, so value for `go,to,with` will be zero.

The problem is that, which data structure should i consider for this to be able to fond keywords in vector and update their value for a given word? i don't have any idea how can i implement it.

Comment: Did you try to use a list? Did you try any data structure and find it lacking? - if so show us and tell us why it didn't work for you? What do you need your data structure to do? What constraints does the data structure have? This isn't a discussion forum - your question seems too broad.

Comment: Isn't something like `university=[(1 0 0) (0 1 0) (0 1 0) (0 0 0)]` more reasonable? The data structure to choice can be a simple python `list` or a more complex object. It depends on your goal. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @horcrux it is more similar to what i want and indexing will be easy thank you